# php setcookies function limiation

Tags: php

i need to set the cookie and i know i can do this this with `setcookie` function but i have to set the cookies for infinitives times. Is this possible or not? If yes please, tell me.

Comment: You mean the cookies should not expire?

Comment: This is not a question about php - its a question about HTTP and browsers

Answer (score 3):

You can set as many cookies as you like, each with its own `setcookie` call, but different clients may have cookie limits. For example, according to [this page](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/05/17/browser-cookie-restrictions/):

- MSIE 7 and 8 have a per-domain limit of 50 cookies
- Firefox also has a limit of 50 cookies per domain
- Opera is lower, at 30 cookies
- Safari 3 has no apparent cookie limit

Try and keep the number of cookies under 30, because Opera is the lowest limit.

Better still, use `$_SESSION` instead! You can have literally unlimited session data, all with only *one* cookie set - the session ID.

**Note:** though my advice may still apply, I've just realised that you probably actually mean a non-expiring cookie. There is no option to do an infinite, non-expiring cookie, but you can set the expires value to a really high value (`INT_MAX`, anyone?)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as noted, the manual page for setcookie is the first answer on google, so you really didn't search. [Here it is](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.setcookie.php).

Now, for what you ask, I don't think it is possible. And it's for the good. Cookies are pretty invasive, so they should not stay infinitely on a client computer. However, you still can put a huge number as $expire value (though you should not !).